# ARM Cortex-A9 Preload and Lock Code in L2 Cache

Tags: caching, arm, zynq, cortex-a

I've been studying and experimenting with the caches on an ARM Cortex-A9, namely a Zynq SoC, for the past week with the main objective of loading and locking part of my code to L2 (PL310). The steps I take to achieve this are:

- Set TTBR0 and Invalidate TLBS
- Invalidate L1 Inst and Data Caches and L2 Cache
- Init and Enable L2 Cache
- Enable L1 Data and Inst and MMU
- Unlock all L2 ways. Run a loop loading the code (using symbols defined in the linker script for the memory region I target). I've tried using three types of instructions for loading - LDR, PLD and PLI. Lock all L2 ways.

The code for loading is:

```
extern uint32_t code_start;
extern uint32_t code_end;

void PreloadCode() {
    uint32_t* temp;
    uint32_t dummy;

    //invalidate all ways and L1 data cache
    L1ICacheInvalidate();
    *REG7_CLEAN_INV_WAY = 0xffff;
    while(*REG7_CLEAN_INV_WAY);
    *REG9_CACHE_SYNC = 0;
    while(*REG9_CACHE_SYNC);

    //unlock all ways
    *REG9_D_LOCKDOWN0 = 0x0000;
    *REG9_I_LOCKDOWN0 = 0x0000;

    asm volatile ("dsb");
    asm volatile ("isb");

    for(temp = &code_start; temp < &code_end; temp += 1){
        asm volatile ("ldr %0, [%1]" : "=r"(dummy) : "r"(temp));
    //  asm volatile ("pld [%0]" :: "r"(temp) : "memory");
    //  asm volatile ("pli [%0]" :: "r"(temp) : "memory");
    }

    asm volatile ("dsb");
    asm volatile ("isb");

    //lock all ways
    *REG9_D_LOCKDOWN0 = 0xFFFF;
    *REG9_I_LOCKDOWN0 = 0xFFFF;

}
```

I also set up the event counters in the PL310 to count the number of IRHIT (instruction read hits) and IRREQ(instruction read requests). I run a piece of code periodically, resetting the counters at each loop and also invalidating L1 instruction cache.

I was hoping to verify that after each loop I would see the number of hit and requests for instructions in L2 to be the same. However, this does not happen. The number of hits is always 0 which suggests I've locked all L2 but the code was not loaded.

When I run the exact same code without locking L2 at the end. I get the first loop of 0 % hit rate, but all subsequent loops show a 100 % hit.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I'm only using one of the CPUs.

Edit: Another note. I use a direct mapping where the VA corresponds directly to the PA. The region I want to load is configured in the page table as Outer and Inner Write-Back, Write-Allocate.